# Java - Method is changing other instances of the same object type

Tags: java

The method evalBoard() below takes brd, and copies it's parameters into pos. It then iterates through some possible values, making changes to pos by calling makeMove().  These calls to pos.makeMove are somehow changing the values inside brd as well.  It can be seen clearly by stepping through the area I've marked in evalBoard. Why is this happening?

```
public Move evalBoard(Board brd) {
    // evaluates current board and returns point of best move

    Move best;
    Move tmp = new Move(-1, -1, LOSE, brd.getPlayer());
    if (brd.getPlayer() == PLAYER1) {
        best = new Move(-1, -1, LOSE, PLAYER1);
    } else {
        best = new Move(-1, -1, WIN, PLAYER2);
    }
    // check if board is empty if so return optimal move
    //

    if (brd.isEmpty()) {

        return (new Move(0, 0, 0, PLAYER1));

    }

    // iterate through possible moves
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (brd.getSpace(x, y) == ' ') {
                // copy all of brd to pos

                pos=new Board(brd.getBoard(),brd.getPlayer());

                tmp.setX(x);
                tmp.setY(y);
                tmp.setPlayer(brd.getPlayer());
/*
 *   problem can be seen by stepping through the next line.  brd is changed at the same time.
*/
                pos.makeMove(tmp);//Problem is here this call is changing brd as well

                // evaluate for immediate win or loss
                if (brd.getPlayer() == PLAYER1) {
                    if (pos.win()) {// immediate win
                        tmp.setValue(WIN);
                        return tmp;
                    } else { // not a winning move check it's recursive
                                // value
                        pos.setPlayer(PLAYER2);
                        tmp.copyFrom(evalBoard(pos));
                        if (tmp.getValue() >= best.getValue()) {
                            best.copyFrom(tmp);
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    if (pos.win()) {// immediate loss
                        tmp.setValue(LOSE);
                        return tmp;
                    } else {// not a losing move check it's recursive value
                        pos.setPlayer(PLAYER1);
                        tmp.copyFrom(evalBoard(pos));
                        if (tmp.getValue() <= best.getValue()) {
                            best.copyFrom(tmp);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return best;

}
```

Here's the Board class:

```
public class Board {
final boolean PLAYER1=true;
final boolean PLAYER2=false;
public char[][] board = new char[3][3];
public boolean Turn;

public Board(char[][] brd,boolean plr1){
    board=brd;
    Turn=plr1;

}
public char getPlayerChar(){
    if (Turn==PLAYER1){
        return 'X';
    }else{
        return 'O';
    }
        }
public char[][] getBoard(){
    return board;
}
public void setBoard(char[][] brd){
    board=brd;
}
public void displayBoard(){
    for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
            System.out.print(board[x][y]);
            if (x<2){
                System.out.print(" | ");
            } 

        }
        System.out.println("");
        if (y<2){
            System.out.println("----------");

        }

    }
}
public void makeMove(Move mv){
    //System.out.println("hit");

    if (mv.getPlayer()==PLAYER1){
        board[mv.getX()][mv.getY()]='X';
    }else{
        board[mv.getX()][mv.getY()]='O';
    }

}
public void setPlayer(boolean plr){
    Turn=plr;
}
public boolean getPlayer(){
    return Turn;
}
public char getSpace(int x,int y){
    return board[x][y];

}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){

            if(!(board[x][y]==' ')){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean win(){
    char plrChar;
    //returns true if board is winning position for current player
    if (Turn==PLAYER1){
        plrChar='X';
    }else {
        plrChar='O';
    }
    //Across
    for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
        if (board[0][y]+board[1][y]+board[2][y]==(plrChar+plrChar+plrChar)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    //Up/Down
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
        if (board[x][0]+board[x][1]+board[x][2]==(plrChar+plrChar+plrChar)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    //Diagonals
        //top left to bottom right
    if (board[0][0]+board[1][1]+board[2][2]==(plrChar+plrChar+plrChar)){
        return true;
    }
        //bottom left to top right
    if (board[0][2]+board[1][1]+board[2][0]==(plrChar+plrChar+plrChar)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
  pos=new Board(brd.getBoard(),brd.getPlayer());
```

you are creating a new Board (in `pos`) that *shares* its `board` array with the original `Board` (in `brd`).  That's what the `Board` constructor is doing here:

```
  public Board(char[][] brd,boolean plr1){
      board=brd;
      ...
```

Naturally, since there is only one array, when you update it via one `Board` the changes are visible via the other `Board`.

If you don't want the old and new `Board` instances to share the same char array, then you should not assign like that.  Instead, you should use a nested loop to copy the state from `brd` to `board`.

---

### The Lesson to be learned

This is an example of a *"leaky abstraction"*.  The `getBoard` and `setBoard` methods allow code external to the `Board` to damage the state of a `Board` instance ... in a rather unexpected way.  Non-leaky versions of these methods and the `Board` constructor would copy the contents of the array (may be to a new array) rather than allowing the `Board`s array instance to be accessible outside of the abstraction boundary.

Comment: Thanks!  I've got it working now.  I made a method to copy the array with loops.